# libperf PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES

Tags: kernel, perf

I am using libperf on a x86_64 CPU to measure the PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES and PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES counters when a given piece of code runs. I do it in two different ways and I expect to get similar numbers but this doesn't happen.

The events are setup like shown below:

```
struct read_format {
  uint64_t nr;
  struct {
    uint64_t value;
    uint64_t id;
  } values[ 2 ];
};

static void pevnt_init(int cpu_id) {
  struct perf_event_attr pea;
  int                    fd1 = -1;
  int                    fd2 = -1;
  int                    tid = syscall(__NR_gettid);

  memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
  pea.type           = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
  pea.size           = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
  pea.config         = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_REFERENCES;
  pea.disabled       = 1;
  pea.pinned         = 1;
  pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
  pea.exclude_hv     = 1;
  pea.exclude_idle   = 1;
  pea.read_format    = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;

  fd1 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, tid, cpu_id, -1, 0);
  if (fd1 != -1) {
    ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &perf_ids[ cpu_id].id_cache_refs);

    memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
    pea.type           = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pea.size           = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pea.config         = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES;
    pea.disabled       = 1;
    pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
    pea.exclude_hv     = 1;
    pea.exclude_idle   = 1;
    pea.read_format    = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;

    fd2 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, tid, cpu_id, fd1, 0);
    if (fd2 != -1) {
      ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &perf_ids[ cpu_id].id_cache_misses);
    }
  }
  printf("perf_event_open :: %6d :: %2d :: %5d :: %5d\n", tid, cpu_id, fd1, fd2); 

  perf_ids[ cpu_id ].pevfd = fd1;
}
```

Method 1:

```
execute the code below for 10 seconds {
  ioctl(perf_ids[ cpu_id].pevfd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
  do_work();
  ioctl(perf_ids[ cpu_id].pevfd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
  read(perf_ids[ cpu_id].pevfd, &rf, sizeof(rf));
  accumulate the counters that have been read
}
```

Method 2:

```
ioctl(perf_ids[ cpu_id].pevfd, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
execute do_work for 10 seconds
read(perf_ids[ cpu_id].pevfd, &rf, sizeof(rf));
```

So the main difference between Method 1 and Method 2 is that Method 2 let's the kernel to accumulates the counters.

The results provided by the methods are sometime very different. I understand that doing enable/disable has some impact on the counters but I don't expect so large differences.

Do you have any ideas on what can be wrong?

Regards,

Comment: Show the exact code of `do_work()`. If it's written in C/C++, show also the assembly the code. Mention the kernel version and CPU model.